# Unable to require openssl when initialling rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the error below when installing rails on osx maverick. OpenSSL has been installed already. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your OpenSSL CA Bundle, per [these instructions from chruby about Ruby 2.1.2](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/Ruby#install-212) which state:

Install 2.1.2

Note: MRI 2.1.2 requires OpenSSL >= 1.0.1.

```
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
cd ruby-2.1.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2
make
sudo make install
```

Note: OS X users must [update their OpenSSL CA cert bundle](https://github.com/raggi/openssl-osx-ca#readme) and properly set ./configure --with-opt-dir to compile against Homebrew's libraries:

```
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
cd ruby-2.1.2
./configure --prefix="$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2" --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl):$(brew --prefix readline):$(brew --prefix libyaml):$(brew --prefix gdbm):$(brew --prefix libffi)"
make
sudo make install
```

For me, it was enough to just [update my OpenSSL CA cert bundle](https://github.com/raggi/openssl-osx-ca#readme) via Homebrew and then reinstall Ruby using ruby-install

```
brew tap raggi/ale
brew install openssl-osx-ca
ruby-install ruby 2.1.2
```

After I performed the above steps, the issue stopped presenting itself.

Comment: THANK YOU. I also only had to update my OpenSSL CA cert bundle via Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

For me... I had tried installing ruby 2.1.2 with `ruby-install` (since I use `chruby` for my ruby version manager). I had tried manually installing `openssl` with homebrew, etc. But I still couldn't get `ruby-install` to successfully build ruby 2.1.2. I've also had similar issues in the past with installing rubies and [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) worked then so I gave I gave it a shot here and it worked! As I understand it, ruby-build is the installer used by `rbenv`.

What I did was:

1. `rm -rf ~/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2` (This is where my ruby installs are installed at.)
2. `brew remove --force openssl`
3. `brew install ruby-build`
4. restart console to be safe
5. `ruby-build 2.1.2 ~/.rubies/ruby-2.1.2`

And success! `ruby-build` seems to be much smarter than `ruby-install` at successfully installing weird dependencies. I'm done with `ruby-install` at this point -- it's given me too many problems! (`brew remove --force ruby-install`)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue.
A fix to rvm was introduced [just yesterday](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3923), and it was not yet merged with rvm master branch, so this is how you do it:

```
rvm get branch /bugfix/3923_set_osx_brew_openssl_compiler_config
rvm install 2.4.0
gem install rails
```

If that works for you, [go to the issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3923) and tell the developer how much you appreciate his effort:

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was struggling with ruby installations due to the recent auto-update in openssl version from 1.0 to 1.1.
I found out that the ruby version < 2.4 does not work with openssl version > 1.0.

I was not even able to revert back the openssl to 1.0 version because other libs has dependencies on it.

No other solution except the one given below worked for me:

`brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p551 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0'
gem update --system`

Now my ruby runs with openssl 1.0 whereas all other libraries are running on the default openssl version 1.1.

Answer (score -3):

secure server is the reason of this issue. You can Install it by using this command:

```
 gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
```

by default its using https://rubygem.org as the source for the gem.

```
 $ gem install rails ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception) Unable to
  require openssl, install OpenSSL and 
  rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

so we can specify a source, `http//:rubygems.org` which is a non-HTTPS source.